# Returning multiple values from simular hash keys powershell

Tags: powershell, hash, key, return

I have the following code that pulls in some server information from a text file and spits it into a hashtable.

```
Get-Content $serverfile | Foreach-Object {     

    if($_ -match '^([^\W+]+)\s+([^\.+]+)')
    {        
            $sh[$matches[1]] = $matches[2]     
    }    
}

$sh.GetEnumerator()| sort -Property Name
```

This produces the following:

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                         
----                           -----                                                                                                         
Disk0                          40                                                                                                            
Disk1                          40                                                                                                            
Disk2                          38                                                                                                            
Disk3                          43                                                                                                            
Memory                         4096                                                                                                          
Name                           Value                                                                                                         
Number_of_disks                1                                                                                                             
Number_of_network_cards        2                                                                                                             
Number_of_processors           1                                                                                                             
ServerName                     WIN02
```

Depending on the server there may be one Disk0 or many more.

My challenge here is to pull each Disk* value from each of the varying number of Disk keys and return the values in a comma separated list, for example;

```
$disks = 40,40,38,43
```

I have tried varying approaches to this problem however none have met the criteria of being dynamic and including the ',' after each disk.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear (at least to me) what you want. You have a hash table, assuming you are happy with? Now you just want to get the values for all disks in a comma separated list. Do you want an array of values, or a string with commas?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that when you say "Depending on the server there may be one Disk0 or many more", you mean "one Disk or many more", each with a different number? You can't have more than one Disk0, because key names can't be duplicated in a hash.

This will give you a list of all the hash values for keys starting with "Disk":

```
$sh.Keys | ?{$_ -match '^Disk'} | %{$sh.$_}
```

If you actually want to get a comma-separated list (a single string value), you can use the **-join** operator:

```
$disks = ($sh.Keys | ?{$_ -match '^Disk'} | %{$sh.$_}) -join ','
```

However, if the reason you want a comma-separated list is in order to get an array of the values, you don't really need the comma-separated list; just assign the results (which are already an array) to the variable:

```
$disks = $sh.Keys | ?{$_ -match '^Disk'} | %{$sh.$_}
```

Note, BTW, that hashes are not ordered. There's no guarantee that the order of the keys listed will be the same as the order in which you added them or in ascending alphanumeric order. So, in the above example, your result could be `38,40,43,40`. If order does matter (i.e. you're counting on the values in **$disks** to be in the order of their respective Disk numbers, you have two options.

1. Filter the listing of the keys through **Sort-Object**:

   ```
   $sh.Keys | ?{$_ -match '^Disk'} | sort |  %{$sh.$_}
   ```

   (You *can* put the `| sort` between `$sh.Keys` and `| ?{...`, but it's more efficient this way...which makes little difference here but would matter with larger data sets.)
2. Use an ordered dictionary, which functions pretty much the same as a hash, but maintains the keys in the order added:

   ```
   $sh = New-Object System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary
   ```